# Embeddable database alternative to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

We are trying identifying an alternative for MySQL
Since the Oracle takeover of Sun a commercial license is now needed for this product. We currently include the MySQL server, LIBMYSQL.DLL (C API) and JDBC driver (JAVA API) with our products.

We need to investigate alternatives that will not require commercial licensing. Options that we have:

1. Using an older version of MySQL pre-Oracle acquisition
2. PostgreSQL or MariaDB may be options
3. Any other options which satisfies our above requirements?

Can give us your suggestions?

Comment: Why is a license required? MySQL is GPL-licensed. Oracle cannot stop you from using it in any way you want.

Comment: We are packaging the MySQL with our product. MySQL can be used in that way also as free?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer. We're not lawyers, and anything you get from us will get laughed out of court when you say "but some random person on the Interwebitubes said it was ok!"

Comment: You would have needed a commercial license *before* the acquisition as well. That's the nature of the GPL license - and that did not change. And MariaDB is not an alternative for the same reason.

Comment: If you're considering bundling PostgreSQL, *please* don't just silent-install the EnterpriseDB installer. Use the .zip binary distribution and have your application install its own service (running on a port other than the default 5432) or manage the server via `pg_ctl` on demand. That way your PostgreSQL instance won't conflict with any that the user may install themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start from, how much is true that a commercial license is now required for MySQL? From the [Oracle page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) it looks that next to commercial they also still have the GPL-licensed open source version.

Comment: A commercial license was **always** required if you packaged MySQL with non-GPL software.

Comment: Yep, but not necessarily if you had the user install it themselves and only talked to it via ODBC or another generic interface that didn't require linking to the client libraries. I seem to recall that MySQL's opinion was a little odd there, and of course this is only vague recollection, so I'd talk to a lawyer before doing anything.